# In TFS 2017 build - how do I print to build log from a command line step?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I'm running a C# console application in a build step in TFS 2017.

I'm running this application in a command line build step and I'm writing output using:
Console.WriteLine()

The output does not show on the build log.

Should I write to the build log in a different manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the `exe` path in `Tool` argument of `Command Line` task. Check my example below:

[image]

Comment: My screen in TFS 2017 looks a little different - but this is what I was missing!
I just had to add the "working folder" path and the stdout magically start showing up
Thanks!